# Numbers stuck at the plot top (GGPLOT2)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a "volcano" plot, but when do a simple plot:

```
v <- ggplot(df, aes(x = log2i, y = -log10(adjpi))
) +
  geom_point() + ylim(0, 12)
v
```

some values go at the top... I guess is something related with the `-log10` transformation but can't make what I want (all of them spread over as in the pic [image])

(.cvs data here : https://ufile.io/5xjx8tc4 )

any help?
thanks!

Comment: How are your x-values calculated?

Comment: Hi, thanks for asking. Values were provided by a facility. I forgot to mention they included the code for this, but by using Plotly (I ve never used it), here it is: 

'plot_ly(dfr_c_wt, x = ~log2_FC, y = ~-log10(adj.P.Val), type = "scatter",
        text = ~paste("ID: ", rownames(dfr_c_wt),
                      "\nDesc: ", gsub("OS=.*", "", dfr_c_wt$Desc),
                      "\nFC: ", round(log2_FC, 2),
                      "\n-log10 adj.Pval: ", round(-log10(adj.P.Val), 3),
                      "\nadjusted pvalue: ", adj.P.Val)) %>%
  layout(title = "c vs wt")'

Comment: Hi, got a response from the facility, some values were somehow rounded to zero, so the Log transformation did not work. You can delete the post or close it, thanks!